# Symfony 5 Mailer undefined method named "htmlTemplate"

Tags: php, symfony, mailer

I'm looking to use [Symfony Mailer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html) Inside a personal project. The idea is the user subscribe to a newsletter, then he received a mail that confirm he subscribe.
I've made a function send Mail inside my controller to call this function when the form is submit.

```
    function sendEmail(MailerInterface $mailer, $useremail)
    {
        $email = (new Email())
            ->from('mail@mail.exemple')
            ->to($useremail)
            ->subject('Great !')
            ->htmlTemplate('emails/signup.html.twig');

        $mailer->send($email);
        return $email;
    }

     /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function index(Request $request, MailerInterface $mailer)
    {
        $mailing = new Mailing();
        $form = $this->createForm(MailingType::class, $mailing);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $task = $form->getData();


            $this->sendEmail($mailer , $request->request->get('mailing')['email']);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');

        }
```

When I submit the form, Everything is okay but when it come inside my `sendEmail` function the following error appear :

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "htmlTemplate" of class
>   "Symfony\Component\Mime\Email".

Do you have any idea about why this error appear ? I'don't understand what's happening.

THank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use a template, you need to use a TemplatedEmail as described in the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#html-content)

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail;
```

```
function sendEmail(MailerInterface $mailer, $useremail)
{
  $email = (new TemplatedEmail())
    ->from('mail@mail.exemple')
    ->to($useremail)
    ->subject('Great !')
    ->htmlTemplate('emails/signup.html.twig');

  $mailer->send($email);
  return $email;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use 'TemplatedEmail' rater than 'Email' class

Comment: Thank you I didn't realize it. THanks a lot.